# Is it possible to add a value in MVC2 RC DataTokens collection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC2 RC and I have built security on top of the Areas/Controller/Action specification, using basically a table that tells the infrastructure which role has permission to execute which controller action.

The code I used to get the "area" was this

```
RouteData.Values["area"]
```

And then I checked that in the Database. My problem is that when I migrated from MVC 1 RTM to MVC2 RC, the **area** goes in the DataTokens collection, and if the controller that is being called is in the root area, the following code returns null

```
RouteData.DataTokens["area"]
```

Do you know if there's any way to tell MVC that if "area" is not in the DataTokens collection, it should have string.Empty?

I'm trying to avoid modifying my code to check that for null.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply check if RouteData.DataTokens["area"] is null (or empty) and assume the default area when it is?

**Edit**

Apologies, I didn't read the the last line of your question before answering. What's the issue with modifying the code?

Comment: Because I'm using it in a lot of places. But that's what I'll do, I have to change RouteData.Values for RouteData.DataTokens anyway

Comment: If you have to change it in a lot of places you may want to take another look at how and when you're performing the evaluation. A simple ActionFilter on your [base] controller would easily do the job for all of the affected actions if implemented correctly. Good luck!

Comment: Thx Nathan for the comments, finally I created an extension method on ControllerContext that gives me Area and changed every piece of code I had with this (not much code because it's the security infrastructure). This way if Area changes again, I have a single place to change it!

Answer (score 1):

As a work around, you can manually add the value from RouteData.Values to RouteData.DataTokens. But ideally you need to address the root cause.

Here's the work around for the issue:

```
        if (controllerContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("area"))
        {
            ControllerContext.RouteData.DataTokens.Add("area", ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["area"]);
        }
```